# Style WooCommerce Product Search Widget

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I got this custom CSS code for the WooCommerce product search bar on the generatepress forums, thanks to David.

When I enter that custom CSS code, the search bar looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CMdx.jpg

```
.woocommerce-product-search {
    border-radius: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse
}

.woocommerce-product-search input {

    border-radius: 0 40px 40px 0;
    border-left: 0
}

.woocommerce-product-search button:before {
    content: "seach";
    font-family: "Arial";
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.woocommerce-product-search button {
    font-size: 0px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 40px 0 0 40px;
}
```

I want the bar to stay that way but with the "search" button on the right side, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaOMt.jpg

Please, could you help me to do it? I would appreciate it very much.

***---EDIT 12/11/2020---***

**HTML:**

```
<div class="woocommerce widget_product_search"><form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="https://example.com/">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="woocommerce-product-search-field-0">Search for:</label>
    <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-0" class="search-field" placeholder="Search products&hellip;" value="" name="s" />
    <button type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will solve the issue without seeing the html, but give it a try:

```
.woocommerce-product-search {
      border-radius: 40px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I already added the html code in the last part of the question.